# MySQL get products with a relation

Tags: mysql

I'm running into a problem with fetching records from my database. I have products and the products have properties. There is a pivot table that connects the product_properties to the product. A product can have multiple properties.

Now my database structure:

*product*

```
| id | title            |
-------------------------
| 1  | Mercedes A green |
| 2  | Volvo V40 green  |
| 3  | Audi A3 green    |
```

*property_value*

```
| id | property_id | value    |
-------------------------------
| 1  |           1 | Volvo    |
| 2  |           1 | Mercedes |
| 3  |           2 | Green    |
| 4  |           1 | Audi     |
```

*product_property*

```
| product_id | property_id | property_value_id | no column, just info
------------------------------------------------
|          1 |           1 |                 2 | Mercedes
|          1 |           2 |                 3 | Green
|          2 |           1 |                 1 | Volvo
|          2 |           2 |                 3 | Green
|          3 |           1 |                 4 | Audi
|          3 |           2 |                 3 | Green
```

**Now I want to get all products that are Mercedes OR Volvo, AND green.** I would expect product.id 1 & 2 to be returned.

So I was thinking of something like this:

```
SELECT product.*
FROM product
  JOIN product_property ON product.id = product_property.product_id
WHERE
   product_property.property_value_id IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY product.id;
```

But this of course returns me all products 1, 2 and 3.

So I need to do something like this:

```
SELECT product.*
FROM product
  JOIN product_property ON product.id = product_property.product_id
WHERE
   (product_property.property_id = 1 AND product_property.property_value_id IN (1, 2))
   AND
   (product_property.property_id = 2 AND product_property.property_value_id IN (3))
GROUP BY product.id;
```

But this returns nothing.

I think I'm close, but I just can't figure out the last step for this query. Who knows...

Comment: I've not studied it closely, so I may be wrong, but this design seems a little suspect to me.

Comment: @Strawberry, I don't see anything wrong with this design. This is how the internet (stackoverflow) describes the usage of product properties. There is a 4th tabel that holds all properties (brand / color), but I didn't mention it here because it is not needed for my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT product.id, product.title
FROM product
  JOIN product_property ON product.id = product_property.product_id
WHERE
   product_property.property_value_id IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY product.id, product.title
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN property_value_id IN (1,2) THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
       COUNT(CASE WHEN property_value_id IN (3) THEN 1 END) > 0
```

The `HAVING` clause uses *conditional aggregates* to check for products being related to *at least one* `property_value_id` of either 1 or 2 **and** related to `property_value_id=3`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb01a/1)

Comment: Sorry for my late reply! But this does the job! Thank you very much! I knew I was close an maybe needed the use `having`, but just couldn't make te last step.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this - possibly a little slower than Giorgios's answer (which I suspect is itself a little slower than simply running a couple of LEFT JOINs)...

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM product_property x 
  JOIN property_value y 
    ON y.property_id = x.property_id 
   AND x.property_value_id = y.id 
  JOIN product p
    ON p.id = x.product_id
 GROUP 
    BY product_id
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN x.property_id = 1 THEN y.value END) IN ('Volvo','Mercedes')
   AND MAX(CASE WHEN x.property_id = 2 THEN y.value END) IN ('Green');
```

Comment: I didn't test your query because you use the values instead of id's.

Comment: what doe you mean? See the answer of Giorgos Betsos, he uses the `property_value_id` instead of iets value.

Comment: The URL will be build from a HTML form that contains the filters. That will use the id's instead of the value

Comment: For now it the query runs in juist a couple of ms. Database not so big jet, we will see how this runs in future.